# How do you structure a local data source using RxJava and Realm?

Tags: android, realm, mvp, rx-java2

I'm super excited that Realm now supports RxJava 2 which introduces the asFlowable functionality so thank you to anyone that contributed to this.

The problem I'm facing is how to best manage the life cycle of realm instances in my local data source singleton class. My local data source is similar to the Android architecture sample [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/blob/todo-mvp-rxjava/todoapp/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/architecture/blueprints/todoapp/data/source/local/TasksLocalDataSource.java). In the Realm examples for RxJava, they instantiate a realm instance in the onCreate and close it in the onDestroy of the activity. However, since my local data source is a singleton, I won't have these lifecycle events to instantiate and close the instance.

The question is: should I instantiate a realm instance every time the singleton is created and close it only when the singleton is destroyed or should I instantiate a realm instance in the activity/fragment, inject it into the local data source, and then close it in the activity/fragment?
Any other suggestions are welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> they instantiate a realm instance in the onCreate and close it in the onDestroy of the activity

That's for the UI thread Realm.

> inject it into the local data source

The `Realm` instance you receive is a thread-local reference-counted instance, not a "thread-safe" singleton. So you probably shouldn't inject `Realm` directly, as then it'll be confined to one given thread.

---

Generally the UI thread Realm can be managed by `ViewModel`, `retained fragment`, `onCreate()`/`onDestroy()` and all that, because Realm provides notifications only if the RealmResults is valid, which means the Realm instance is open.

So to expose the RealmResults on any thread, agnostic of the fact that it is a RealmResults, you would need to do

```
public Flowable<List<ChatsModel>> getAllChatsData(Realm realm) {
    RealmQuery<ChatsModel> query = realm.where(ChatsModel.class);
    if(realm.isAutoRefresh()) {
        return query.findAllAsync().asFlowable().filter(RealmResults::isLoaded);
    } else {
        return Flowable.just(query.findAll());
    } 
}
```

As you can see, this receives the `Realm` instance as its input. Now, if you want to remove that parameter, you'd need to hide the reference counting in whatever you're exposing from the local data source, for which I personally find `LiveData` to be the best bet - as it has `onActive()`/`onInactive()` callbacks.

```
public class RealmLiveData<T extends RealmModel> extends MutableLiveData<List<T>> {
    public interface QueryDefinition<M extends RealmModel> {
        RealmResults<M> createResults(Realm realm);
    }

    private final QueryDefinition<T> queryDefinition;

    public RealmLiveData(QueryDefinition<T> query) {
        this.queryDefinition = query;
        // TODO: handle realm config other than DefaultConfig if needed
    }

    Realm realm;
    RealmResults<T> results;
    RealmChangeListener<RealmResults<T>> realmChangeListener = new RealmChangeListener<RealmResults<T>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChange(RealmResults<T> results) {
            if(results.isLoaded()) {
                setValue(results);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActive() {
        realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        results = queryDefinition.createResults(realm);
        results.addChangeListener(realmChangeListener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onInactive() {
        setValue(Collections.emptyList());
        results.removeChangeListener(realmChangeListener);
        realm.close();
        realm = null;
    }
}
```

Then you could expose a LiveData:

```
public class MyDao {
    public LiveData<List<MyObject>> findMyObjectsWithChanges() {
        return new RealmLiveData<MyObject>(new QueryDefinition<MyObject>() {
             @Override
             public RealmResults<MyObject> createResults(Realm realm) {
                 return realm.where(MyObject).findAllAsync();
             }
        });
    }
}
```

Lambda expressions make that a lot nicer

```
public class MyDao {
    public LiveData<List<MyObject>> findMyObjectsWithChanges() {
        return new RealmLiveData<MyObject>((realm) -> realm.where(MyObject.class).findAllAsync());
    }
}
```

So that's a possibility worth looking into.

Answer (score 1):

Note, that not closing the Realm file on the UI thread isn't necessarily dangerous as it is automatically kept up to date. The only downside is that you can no longer use functionality that requires the file to be fully closed, like for example deleting it.

Personally, I think that lifecycle events do belong in the model layer as you often need them for other things like controlling sensors and/or GPS.

Especially now that Architecture Components have reached 1.0 I would recommend looking at the LifecycleObservable as means for controlling the Realm instance: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/lifecycle.html